# Subclass numpy.ndarray without 'propagating' subtype

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a Python-based system which operates on abstract simplified representations of floor plans. Currently, a floor plan is represented as a plain NumPy array, and operations on it are implemented as functions which accept that array:

```
floor_plan = numpy.ndarray(...)

def find_rooms(floor_plan: numpy.ndarray) ...
```

I'd like to refactor the system to instead use a dedicated floor plan class, with these operations defined as method on that class. This will allow me to also store supplementary information on floor plan instances, perform centralized caching on its methods, etc.

However, I'd also like to retain the ability to treat a floor plan as an array. At the least, this is useful during the refactoring process, as all existing code will continue to work even when the new class is introduced. I can accomplish this by having my new class inherit from `numpy.ndarray`:

```
class FloorPlan(numpy.ndarray):
  def find_rooms(self) ...

floor_plan = FloorPlan(...)
```

But there's a problem: if I derive an array from an operation on this subtype, then the derived array is *also* of the same subtype:

```
type(floor_plan[:, 0]) == FloorPlan
```

This is intentional by NumPy's design (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.subclassing.html). However, it's not appropriate for my purposes, as a floor plan has discrete semantics which don't necessarily apply to every derived value.

Is there any way to disable or avoid this 'propagation' of my array subtype to derived arrays?

Comment: Would it be acceptable to store the numpy array as an attribute of the class instead? Check out [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Comment: Composition would require refactoring the operational code in lockstep with the rollout of the new class — any code which references the plain-array floor plan would need to be updated to refer to the array attribute on the class instance.

A subclass, in contrast, could be introduced 'silently', and then the operational code could subsequently be refactored at will. Since the codebase I'm working in is quite messy, I highly value the ability to break down the refactoring process into small discrete steps.